# How do I calculate a point's coordinates on a circle’s circumference

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

[image]

I have got a circle with radius $r$ and center point $c_x$ and $c_y$.

Known values:
- $c_x$ and $c_y$
- $r$
- length $AR_a$
- length $BR_b$

Angle between point $A$ and the radius $r$ is unknown and angle between $B$ and the radius $r$ is unknown. Is it posible to get coordinates for $A$ and $B$ using any formula?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The radius $r$ appears both in the list of knowns and unknowns... What have you tried ? Where do you encounter a difficulty ?

Comment: It's angle between radius and A is unknown and angle between radius and B is unknown. I'll try to write it in different way

Comment: So you mean the unknown is the angle $\widehat{ACR_a}$ where $C$ is the center ? That could be a better way to write it. Could you edit your question and tell us what you have tried, this would help to answer at the appropriate level.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for my writting skills :( @Hagen von Eitzen has provided the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pythagoras to obtain the vertical distance $\sqrt{r^2-|AR_a|^2}$

Comment: Oh, thanks. Your right. I haven't looked at it that way. Now it looks clear :)